# Issues with Pubnub + Wink Hub and sensors

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub, home-automation, wink

I'm trying to get my Wink Hub working with Pubnub subscriptions in my iOS app, but all I ever get is a PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory status in the didReceiveStatus callback.

Here is the code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PNObjectEventListener {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var client: PubNub

    override init() {
        let configuration = PNConfiguration(publishKey: "", subscribeKey: "fake-key")
        client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(configuration)
        super.init()
        client.addListener(self)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        client.subscribeToChannelGroups(
            ["sensor-channel0",
            "sensor-channel1"],
                                        withPresence: false)

        return true
    }

    func client(client: PubNub, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult) {        
        print("receivedMessage")
    }


    func client(client: PubNub, didReceiveStatus status: PNStatus) {        
    if status.category == .PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory {
        print("disconnected")
        // This event happens when radio / connectivity is lost.
    }
}
```

The subscribe and channel keys are taken straight from the device subscription data returned by the Wink API, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can your [reproduce with PN logging enabled](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and put the log file in a gist and provide link to the gist?

Comment: Any progress on the log files @JonahGabriel

Comment: The likely issue is network connectivity from your device. Were you able to verify that?

Comment: It is not a network connectivity issue as I am getting device info for my sensors.